# SQL: IS NULL not working

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to test if a variable is null but I seem to have a syntax error, my code is:

```
DECLARE @count1 INT

SET @count1 = 
(SELECT HPlayedHome FROM League WHERE GameID = 
(SELECT TOP 1 GameID From Goals WHERE Date <= '20130923' AND Home = 'Palermo'
AND (GameID >=2551 AND GameId <= 5100) ORDER BY Date Desc))

SELECT CASE @count1 IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE @count1 END
```

I want the query to return the value of @count1 but if it's NULL return 0.
SQL SERVER 2012 is highlighting a syntax error on IS, 'Incorrect syntax near IS'.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`CASE WHEN` is correct syntax:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN @count1 IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE @count1 END
```

You are aware of the fact that you can shorten this to

```
SELECT ISNULL(@count1, 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two forms of CASE:

```
CASE
    WHEN condition1 THEN result1
    WHEN condition2 THEN result2
    ELSE result3
END

CASE variable
    WHEN value1 THEN result1
    WHEN value2 THEN result2
    ELSE result3
END
```

You could use form 2, but change the IS to WHEN to make it syntactically correct:

```
SELECT CASE @count1 WHEN NULL THEN 0 ELSE @count1 END
```

Unfortunately, the comparison is made using an equality test, and NULL does not equal NULL, so you must use form 1:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN @count1 IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE @count1 END
```

---

There is already a function to deal with nulls: [`COALESCE()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx), which returns the first non-null value passed to it:

```
SELECT COALESCE(@count1, 0)
```